gdb address out differ from std::cout -> where is my mistake?

i am still searching for the vector resize error, see my last post.
after i set an local variable the vector size is overwritten.
now i check the address from the local variables via cout and gdb.
i dont know why the cout printed var address is not the same as gdb.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#pragma pack(4)
typedef struct
{
    struct{
        unsigned char bit_1 : 1;
        unsigned char bit_2 : 1;
        unsigned char bit_3 : 1;
        unsigned char reserve : 5;
    };
    unsigned int w;
}MY_STRUCT;

class c{
    public:
        void init(void);
    protected:
        std::vector<unsigned char> m_d;
};

void c::init()
{
    m_d.clear();
    m_d.resize(8192);
}

class a;

class b : public c{
    public:
        b();
        void init(a* value);
    private:
        a* m_ptr;
};

b::b()
{
    m_ptr = nullptr;
}

void b::init(a* value)
{
    std::cout << "address m_ptr " << &m_ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "address m_d   " << &m_d << std::endl;
    m_ptr = value;
    c::init();
}

class a{
    public:
        void init(void);
    private:
        b m_i;
};

void a::init(void)
{
    m_i.init(this);    
}

int main() {
    a var;
    var.init();
    return 0;
}

cout prints:
address m_ptr 0xbefffca0
address m_d   0xbefffcac

gdb out:
(gdb) print &m_ptr 
$2 = (machine **) 0xbefffcac
(gdb) print &m_d   
$4 = (std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > *) 0xbefffcac

why could the stack or heap corrupted, i found no reason. i check step trough operation via gdb.
what was done:

start new project, only with the delcaration above -> working
comment all not neccessary files out -> was working
comment one more header file out, no matter which one -> not working
one more header in the project -> not working
i change the header files -> not working

after the assignment from m_ptr the var m_d is overwritten and an resize operation did not work, i got an segmentation fault.
the software is cross compiled, if i comment one more header file it seems running,
i can swap the commented out header files, it is equal.
Some ideas howto get rid of, may be it is an compiler bug?
How can i check, why the stack or the address from the variable is wrong?
thanks, sorry again for my post :-(
i am in despair
i try gdb, set breakpoints, set variable watch, new project, comment out, posted on stackoverflow

I check the addresses via gdb in the constructor, i got the same "error" . the addresses are already in the constructor the same

hello, could be the pragma pack(4) the issue? i check the headers again and found that pragma.

Please add gcc and gdb version information.

I don't see a pragma pack(4) in your posted code.

GNU gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2+b3) 8.2.1
gcc version 7.5.0

i know it was here in one of the last included header, i idiot

if it necessary to restore the pragma pack settings with #pragma pack8)?

See here, the usual way is to do #pragma pack(push, 4) before, and #pragma pack(pop) after.

I don't understand what you are complaining about here. The vraibles m_d and m_ptr are different objects, so why do you think their addresses should be the same? When I run the code I get the address of the two variables, followed by a call to clear and resize m_d.

@OldBoy But in gdb out both variables are shown with the same address.

I have tried this using g++ and gdb and the latter prints the same values as the std::cout commands. So I do not see how you are getting different results. You may need to check again.

i add the struct in the c++ code.

What exactly are you trying to achieve with all this code?

I suspect an ODR violation due to the pragma pack affecting code after it such that the code after is different in different translation units.  That could easily mess up the debugger, because it's debug information would be unreliable.

The problem does not reproduce using gcc (GCC) 13.2.1 20240316 (Red Hat 13.2.1-7) and GNU gdb (Fedora Linux) 14.1-4.fc39:
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) b b::init
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40126a: file t.cc, line 46.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, b::init (this=0x7fffffffdd00, value=0x7fffffffdd00) at t.cc:46
46          std::cout << "address m_ptr " << &m_ptr << std::endl;
(gdb) n
address m_ptr 0x7fffffffdd18
47          std::cout << "address m_d   " << &m_d << std::endl;
(gdb) n
address m_d   0x7fffffffdd00
48          m_ptr = value;
(gdb) p &m_ptr
$1 = (a **) 0x7fffffffdd18
(gdb) p &m_d
$2 = (std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > *) 0x7fffffffdd00

If you get different output from GDB and from the program using your test case, there is a bug in either GCC or GDB that you are using. Both are ancient; you should use something much newer.

Hello, you are right. i tested it with an new compiler and it works, but it is an cross compile not so easy to replace the compiler (version). thanks

thanks a lot for the lot comments and answers!
the solution was the following:
#pragma pack(push, 4)
typedef struct
{
    struct{
        unsigned char bit_1 : 1;
        unsigned char bit_2 : 1;
        unsigned char bit_3 : 1;
        unsigned char reserve : 5;
    };
    unsigned int w;
}MY_STRUCT;
#pragma pack(pop)

only #pragma pack(4) messed it up.
thanks again
